# dell optiplex 790 not starting

Tags: cpu, power-supply, gpu, dell-optiplex

I have a dell 790 OPTIPLEX MT. First it starts and, as always, all diagnostics lights flash. Then only the 3rd diagnostic light is solid and nothing gets displayed. Nothing happens and the fans keep on running. What can the issue be? What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked [Dell's documentation of the meaning of the diagnostic lights](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/692037/Dell-Optiplex-790.html?page=68#manual)?

Comment: I have the same problem with DELL 790. 
Sometimes it's starting after a 100 times restarting. 
What did you do with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If it powers up, but no BIOS is displayed there are 3 possible culprits:

- Monitor - Do you have a second one to try?
- RAM - Prevents boot, but is usually accompanied by motherboard BEEP CODES
- Motherboard - With age, motherboard components do fail and cause catastrophic failure.

Comment: I've removed all RAM modules and try with each one but it doesn't seems that issue .... BIOS is also not displayed and i've check on different monitors and with or without GPU too . PC boots up and all works fine just it stops with solid 3rd diagnostic light with digit 3 on it .... Motherboard is of OPTIPLEX 790 Mini Tower Core i7

Comment: According to this article: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln284978/a-reference-guide-to-the-dell-optiplex-diagnostic-indicators?lang=en#2009_to_2012
Diagnostic light 3 indicates a system board failure (motherboard). You need to replace it according to its Model Number.